# K-nearest neighbourhood in a spcific range in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, knn, nearest-neighbor, neighbours

I am dealing with k-neighbour problem in MATLAB. There is an image with row **r** and column **c**. And divide it into **r*c** blocks - each blcok represents a patch centered in each pixel.

And I want to find the k-nearest neighbourbood of each blcok within a specific *search range*. At first I use `knnsearch` with `kdTree`:

`ns = createns(Block','nsmethod','kdtree');
[Index_nearest,dist] = knnsearch(ns,Block','k',k+1);`

However, I find that it would find k-nearest neighbourhood in all blocks, instead of the specific range. Therefore, is there any other method to achieve the goal? Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: the code for knnsearch:

```
function [Index_nearest, Weight] = Compute_Weight(Input, Options) 

% Input the data and pre-processing
    windowsize = Options.winsize;
    k = Options.directionsize;
    deviation = Options.deviation; % Deviation for Gaussian kernel
    h = Options.h; % This parameter is for controling the weights
    [r,c] = size(Input); 

    In_pad  = padarray(Input, [windowsize windowsize], 'symmetric');

    window_size = (2*windowsize+1)*(2*windowsize+1);

    Block = zeros(window_size,r*c); 

%% Split the input data into blocks

    for i = 1:r
        for j = 1:c
            block = In_pad(i:i+2*windowsize,j:j+2*windowsize);
            Block(:,r*(i-1)+j) = block(:); % expand from column to column
       end
    end

%% Find k-nearest neighbour blocks

    % Create a KDtree with all local patches
    ns = createns(Block','nsmethod','kdtree');

    % Find the patches closest by in intensity in relation to the local patch itself
    [Index_nearest,ddd] = knnsearch(ns,Block','k',k+1);
    Index_nearest = Index_nearest';
    Index_nearest = Index_nearest(2:k+1,:);
end
```

Comment: could you give a sample file? The easiest way is probably to loop over the areas and do the `knnsearch` on each sector

Comment: @Finn Yes, sure. I have already uploaded the code for your information.

Comment: @Finn I also thought about the loop. Is there any possibility to find local pacth without the loop?

Comment: I don't think so. it is a knnsearch for each block so you will have to loop over it.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`blockproc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html).